# Selecting Maya objects through memory using classes

Tags: python, class, memory, selection, maya

Selecting Maya objects through memory using classes

What is the problem with the below code:

```py
import maya.cmds as cmds 

class MakeObject:
    def __init__(self):
        self.grp = cmds.createNode('transform')

    def make_cube(self):
        self.cube = cmds.polyCube(n='cube')[0]
        cmds.parent(self.cube, self.grp)
    def selection(self):
        cmds.select(self.cube)


x = MakeObject()
x.make_cube()

y = MakeObject()
y.make_cube()

x.selection()
```

Comment: Trying to select two objects in Maya that share the same name, based on memory not based on selecting the object through full path.

I created a class that should have a function to create a cube and when you create it again using a different instance variable, you also have the ability to select the cube based on the instance variable not based on the full path but it sends and error that there is more than one object that shares the same name.

Comment: Here is the full code:

Comment: import maya.cmds as cmds 

class MakeObject:    
    def __init__(self):
        self.grp = cmds.createNode('transform')
        
    def make_cube(self):
        self.cube = cmds.polyCube(n='cube')[0]
        cmds.parent(self.cube, self.grp)
    def selection(self):
        cmds.select(self.cube)     
x = MakeObject()
x.make_cube()

# creat a cube with the same name as the first cube
y = MakeObject()
y.make_cube()
x.selection()

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. You could use the edit link to update your question instead of posting comments. It will help people better understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike `pymel`, `cmds` doesn't use a wrapper to work with nodes. Instead it uses strings which can be problematic since they don't update dynamically. For example, if you create a new node `my_cube = cmds.polyCube(n='cube')[0]` then rename it, the `my_cube` variable will still be pointing the object's older name.

This could also be a problem if there are multiple objects in the scene that share the same duplicate name. Maya usually auto-renames duplicate naming to avoid conflicts, but it's valid to have duplicate names in different hierarchies. In this case you would have to access it by using the node's long name. For example, an object named `"cube"` that's parented under another object named `"root"` would have a long name `"|root|cube"`.

All this being said, yes, there is a problem with this code. It's making 2 cubes with the same name and re-parenting them to a different hierarchy. So there will be 2 nodes with the name `"cube"`. When the `select` command is called, it's literately calling `cmds.select("cube")`, but since there's more than one `"cube"` Maya has no idea how to interpret that and then throws an error.

What *can* be done is to capture the object's new long name by doing this after it parents: `self.cube = cmds.ls(sl=True, long=True)[0]`

Now it's able to select the first cube as expected.